# MobileFirst admin service throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException now and then

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

We're running MFP 7.0 on WAS ND 8.5.5.5 and SDK 7.0.8.10. Sometimes users experience a "Server error. Contact the server administrator" when performing various actions. Retrying "solves" the issue.

Some snippets from the SystemOut log from a failed action in this case "saving a notification":

`[11/4/15 15:58:25:812 CET] 000000fe BaseTransacti I   myapp: myappserver/mymfpserver/mymfpserver / mymfpip: 2015-11-04T14:58:25.808Z: Application enviroment 'myappApp-android-1.0.9' was updated
[11/4/15 15:58:25:812 CET] 000000fe BaseTransacti I   myapp: myappserver/mymfpserver/mymfpserver / mymfpip: 2015-11-04T14:58:25.808Z: Push environment updated
[11/4/15 15:58:51:498 CET] 00000149 RequestProces E org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor handleRequest An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
[11/4/15 15:58:51:499 CET] 00000149 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [ManagementServlet] in application [worklightadmin_war]. Exception created : [java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException 
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1240) 
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.parseHeaders(MultiPartParser.java:270) 
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.nextPart(MultiPartParser.java:115)
at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart.hasNext(InMultiPart.java:83)
at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart.next(InMultiPart.java:95)`

`[11/4/15 15:58:51:500 CET] 00000149 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[11/4/15 15:58:51:501 CET] 00000149 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ManagementServlet]: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1240) at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.parseHeaders(MultiPartParser.java:270) at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.nextPart(MultiPartParser.java:115) at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart.hasNext(InMultiPart.java:83) at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart.next(InMultiPart.java:95)`

`[11/4/15 15:58:51:504 CET] 0000014a ServiceProxy  E   Received status 500 for PUT http://mymfpserver:myport/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myapp/applications/myappApp/iphone/1.0.9/accessRule?asynch=true
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://mymfpserver:myport/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myapp/applications/myappApp/iphone/1.0.9/accessRule?asynch=true
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:86)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1688)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:341)`

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://mymfpserver:myport/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myapp/applications/myappApp/iphone/1.0.9/accessRule?asynch=true
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1639)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:161)
        ... 30 more`

Since a retry without changing anything "resolves" the issue I suspect an environmental rather then a configuration issue. First thing I checked was for OOMs, which I haven't seen. Then I ran the verbose GC log of the appserver through the GC analyzer tool, but also that didn't give me any clues.

This is the contents of the POST data:
`{"action":"DELETE","message":"","downloadLink":"","multiLanguageMessage":[]}`

Sorry, while capturing the POST data the error looked the same from user perspective, but checking the websphere logs it showed a "Server rejected operation" error:
`[11/9/15 12:40:36:553 CET] 00000113 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause servicesServlet: java.net.ProtocolException: Server rejected operation
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.expect100Continue(HttpURLConnection.java:1059)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1118)`

In the ffdc it shows depth limit reached stacktraces. I tried to paste those here using the ` quotes, but it keeps warning me when I save it that it appears to contain code.

Not sure if the "server rejected opration" error has a relation with the java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. The POST data contents of a failing requests resulting in the java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is:
`{"action":"NOTIFY","message":"Test Dennis 6","downloadLink":"","multiLanguageMessage":[{"locale":"en","language":"English","message":"English message."},{"locale":"nl","language":"Dutch","message":"Dutch message."}]}`

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the PUT request?

Answer (score 0):

The exception could happen with HTTP request headers that do not contain a colon. HTTP 1.1 standard request headers always have a colon. It could be that the headers get scrambled somehow by firewall, load balancer, proxies in your network topology.

Annother possibility: The exception is in the Wink library. The worklightadmin war file contains its own version of Wink. It could happen that this internal version of Wink is in conflict with some other Wink version that exists in the webserver, even in other web applications. Therefore it is important to use the "parent-last" classloader policy.

In the Websphere console: Click *Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers*, and select the server used for IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation.

- If the class loader policy is set to Multiple, do nothing.
- If the class loader policy is set to Single and the class loading mode is set to parent-last, do nothing.
- If the class loader policy is set to Single and the class loading mode is set to parent-first and you have other web apps in the web server, change the class loader policy to Multiple, and set the class loader order of all applications other than MobileFirst applications to parent-first, so that the class loading behavior of all other web apps does not change.

Next, select the "parent-last" policy in the following way:

- Click *Applications > Applications Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > worklightadmin_war*.
- In the Detail Properties section, click the Class loading and update detection link.
- In the Class loader order pane, click Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last). Click OK.
- In the Modules section, click Manage Modules and select the Worklight Administration Services module.
- In the Class loader order pane, click Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last). Then click OK twice and click Safe.

Please restart the webserver after the changes.

Comment: I checked Georg's suggestions and they were all already set like he mentioned, The log output mentioned is for saving a push notification, but the users experience this issue also with deploying/updating wlapps and adding adapters.